# Extend MovieClip class in createjs

Tags: inheritance, extend, createjs

I am trying to extend the MovieClip class. Here is the code:

```js
var MyMovieClip = function() {
  //some code will go here  
}

createjs.extend(MyMovieClip, MovieClip);
```

And i get the following error: createjs.extend is not a function.
I got all scripts included.

I checked the documentation here, and I can't see what I am doing wrong.
http://www.createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/Utility%20Methods.html

Comment: What version of CreateJS are you using? The extend method was added in version 0.8.0. Also, you will need to use `createjs.MovieClip` instead of just `MovieClip`.

Comment: @Lanny, yes Flash CC was using older version of CreateJS. I updated to the newest version, and now it works. And yes I needed to use createjs.MovieClip. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Oh and another thing. I noticed that in Flash, linking options for html canvas project are grayed out. Is there another way I can change the base class of an already existing symbol, from MovieClip to MyMovieClip.

Comment: Unfortunately you can not change base classes currently in Flash. You can do it by modifying the generated source, but I know that is not ideal.

Comment: It's still something. I will give it a try. Thanks :D